# Loading from text file into list

Tags: java, list

I have been trying to read from an external .txt file into a list of "Tasks" to form a ToDo list, but trying to read in more than a single line into the list gives  the following error, which tells me that the array isn't properly expanding to fit the extra lines.

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1

But what I'm asking help for is getting the array to properly fill, when as far as I know, it should be from this function call.

```
public void loadList(boolean showStatus) {                
myList.clear();
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(",");
                Task item = new Task();
                item.setDescription(tokens[0]);
                item.setPriority(Integer.parseInt(tokens[1])); 
                item.setDueDate(tokens[2]);
                item.setStatus(Boolean.parseBoolean(tokens[3]));
                myList.add(item);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ToDoList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ToDoList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (br != null)
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ToDoList.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
        }
    }
```

(For reference, here's the format of the .txt file)

> Assassinate Santa,4,12-25-19,false
>
> Shave Bear,3,03-09-19,false
>
> Level Canada,4,09-09-19,true

Additionally, apparently the parseBoolean attempt doesn't actually read whether the .txt file Tasks are true/false, and is defaulting everything to false.

Comment: check `tokens.length`  - either you have blank lines or badly formatted data

Comment: Oh jeez. It was that stupid. I did indeed have blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] tokens = line.split(",");
if(token.length != 4)
{ 
 // Then you may skip this line and proceed to next line
 continue;
}
// Or do the reading tokens array
```

You can do this to solve the issue mentioned in the comment.